# UICollectionView with text labels from an array

Tags: swift, xcode, uicollectionview, label

I am trying to have a collection view that displays an array of customer testimonials. I have another collection view on the content view which is why part of the code below has an image collection view incorporated. The app runs fine on my phone, but the labels do not display on the screen. What am I doing wrong?

```
@IBOutlet weak var collectionViewTwo: UICollectionView!
let testimonialArray = ["You rock", "You suck"]

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        if collectionView.tag == 1 {
            let cell = collectionViewOne.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "HomeOneCollectionViewCell", for: indexPath) as? HomeOneCollectionViewCell
            cell!.imageOne.image = imageArrayOne[indexPath.row]
            return cell!
        } else {
            let cell = collectionViewTwo.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "HomeTwoCollectionViewCell", for: indexPath) as? HomeTwoCollectionViewCell
            cell?.testimonialLabel?.text = testimonialArray[indexPath.row]
            cell?.testimonialLabel?.textColor = UIColor.white
            return cell!
        }
    }
```

Comment: is your dark mode on ? try to change textColor

Answer (score 0):

Guess you have mistakenly made text colour as white? White label will not display on white background. Commenting the line should show you the results. PFA.

```
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    if collectionView.tag == 1 {
        let cell = collectionViewOne.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "HomeOneCollectionViewCell", for: indexPath) as? HomeOneCollectionViewCell
         cell!.imageOne.image = imageArrayOne[indexPath.row]
        return cell!
    } else {
        let cell = collectionViewTwo.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "HomeTwoCollectionViewCell", for: indexPath) as? HomeTwoCollectionViewCell
        cell?.testimonialLabel?.text = testimonialArray[indexPath.row]
        // cell?.testimonialLabel?.textColor = UIColor.white
        return cell!
    }
}
```

[Please see here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0ukkV.png)